# Why can't Scala find implicit value for parameter scala.slick.session.Session?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I am running a Scala Play 2.2 application with Slick 1.0.1. I am trying to wrap all of my database calls into a future try, for example:

```
object DbTeachers extends Table[DbTeacher]("edu_teachers") {
...
  def insertTeacher(school: Int, userId: String)
                   (implicit ec: ExecutionContext, db: Database) = 
    future { Try { db.withSession => { implicit s: Session =>
      (DbTeachers.school ~ DbTeachers.teacher).insert(school, userId)
  }}}
}
```

I find that the pattern `future { Try { db.withSession => { ACTUAL_CODE_GOES_HERE }}}` creates clutter and I would like to abstract it out as follows:

```
sealed class DbAsync[T](block: => T) {
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
  implicit lazy val db = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())
  def get: Future[Try[T]] = future { Try { db.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
    block 
  }}}
}

object DbAsync {
  def apply[T](block: => T): Future[Try[T]] = new DbAsync[T](block).get
}
```

And then I can write my insertTeacher function as:

```
def insertTeacher(school: Int, userId: String) = DbAsync {
  (DbTeachers.school ~ DbTeachers.teacher).insert(school, userId)
}
```

However, the scala compiler (2.10.2) complains about this: `could not find implicit value for parameter session: scala.slick.session.Session`

According to my understanding, the `insert()` method does have an implicit session variable in scope within the DbAsync block, and because it is a call-by-name parameter, it shouldn't actually be evaluated until it is called within the DbAsync, at which time there would be an implicit session object in scope.

So, my question is, how do I convince the Scala compiler that there actually is an implicit Session object in scope?

Comment: Note that you should not use `defaultContext` for blocking operations. You could create additional `ExecutionContext` with configured thread pool.

Comment: @senia, so, as long as I'm using `defaultContext` within the context of futures that are resolved with `map`, or a promise, then I should be fine, yes?

Comment: I would specify context manually like `future(blockingOperation)(blockingContext)` or `f.map(blockingOperation)(blockingContext)` or even create an actor pool for blocking operations - just to be sure.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `Try` in `Future`. `Future` can hold exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your suggestion is incorrect. It doesn't matter where `call-by-name` parameter will be evaluated. All implicit parameters should be resolved at compile time in the place where they are required.

You could make it work this way:

```
def dbAsync[T](block: Session => T): Future[Try[T]] = {
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
  implicit lazy val db = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())
  future { Try { db.withSession { block }}}
}

def insertTeacher(school: Int, userId: String) = dbAsync { implicit s: Session =>
  (DbTeachers.school ~ DbTeachers.teacher).insert(school, userId)
}
```

Note that you don't need class `DbAsync` nor object `DbAsync`.

Note that you should not use `defaultContext` for blocking operations. You could create additional `ExecutionContext` with configured thread pool.